# Get the most recent submission from a team in a submissions table (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that can be simplified as:

```
ID  |team_id |  submission file  | date     
========================================
1   |  1756  |  final_project.c  |2018-06-22 19:00:00
2   |  1923  |       asdf.c      |2018-06-22 16:00:00
3   |  1756  |     untitled.c    |2018-06-21 20:00:00
4   |  1923  |   my_project.c    |2018-06-21 14:00:00
5   |  1756  |     untitled.c    |2018-06-21 08:00:00
6   |  1814  |   my_project.c    |2018-06-20 12:00:00
```

This is a table of people submitting their projects to me, but I only want each individual students' most recent submission, with each student having a unique team_id.

How do I recall the most recent row of each team_id so that my recall looks like this:

```
ID  |team_id |  submission file  | date   
========================================
1   |  1756  |  final_project.c  |2018-06-22 19:00:00
2   |  1923  |       asdf.c      |2018-06-22 16:00:00
6   |  1814  |   my_project.c    |2018-06-20 12:00:00
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: My question got lost down there in the comments. Do you want the most recent version of all files the team has submitted or just the most recent single file the team has submitted?

Comment: And what version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 1):

`Subquery` will do what you want with *correlation* approach :

```
select t.*
from table t -- Need to replace table with your table-name i.e. Projecttble, etc..
where id = (select t1.id
            from table t1 -- Need to replace table with your table-name 
            where t1.team_id = t.team_id 
            order by t1.date desc 
            limit 1
           );
```

Comment: sorry, to clarify what is t & t1? the name of the table? is t1 a dummy variable?

Comment: @Amira. . . `t` or `t1` is not a variable it is alise of table. You just need to replace `table` with your original name of `table`.

Comment: Add a filter for `submission_file` into your subquery or it will only pull the most recent file for the `team_id`. So in looking back at the OP, it leads me back to the question of @Amira, do you want the most recent version of all files the team has submitted or just the most recent single file the team has submitted?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a self join to pick most recent row per team

```
select a.*
from your_table a
join (
    select team_id, max(date) date
    from your_table 
    group by team_id
) b on a.team_id = b.team_id and a.date = b.date
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Yogesh beat me to the MySQL 5 answer while I was AFK. You'll want to join your subquery on both the `team_id` and the `submission_file` in case you get multiple file submissions from a team on the same day.

Depending on what version of MySQL you are using, this can be done different ways.

**SETUP**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (ID int, team_id int, submission_file varchar(30), the_date date) ;
>
> INSERT INTO t1 (ID,team_id,submission_file,the_date)
> SELECT 1, 1756, 'final_project.c', '2018-06-20 19:00:00' UNION ALL  
> SELECT 2, 1923, 'asdf.c', '2018-06-22 16:00:00' UNION ALL  /**/
> SELECT 3, 1756, 'untitled.c', '2018-06-21 20:00:00' UNION ALL  /**/
> SELECT 4, 1923, 'my_project.c', '2018-06-21 14:00:00' UNION ALL  /**/
> SELECT 5, 1756, 'untitled.c', '2018-06-21 08:00:00' UNION ALL
> SELECT 6, 1814, 'my_project.c', '2018-06-20 12:00:00'  UNION ALL/**/
>
> SELECT 7, 1756, 'final_project.c', '2018-06-21 19:00:00' UNION ALL
> SELECT 8, 1756, 'final_project.c', '2018-06-22 00:00:00' /**/
>
> ;
> ```

**QUERIES**

If you are using MySQL 5.x or lower, then you'll want to use a correlated subquery with a `LIMIT` on it to pull up just the rows you want.

> ```
> /* MySQL <8 */
> SELECT a.*
> FROM t1 a
> WHERE a.id = (
>     SELECT b.id
>     FROM t1 b
>     WHERE b.team_id = a.team_id
>       AND b.submission_file = a.submission_file
>     ORDER BY b.the_date DESC
>     LIMIT 1
> ) ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | team_id | submission_file | the_date  
> -: | ------: | :-------------- | :---------
>  2 |    1923 | asdf.c          | 2018-06-22
>  3 |    1756 | untitled.c      | 2018-06-21
>  4 |    1923 | my_project.c    | 2018-06-21
>  6 |    1814 | my_project.c    | 2018-06-20
>  8 |    1756 | final_project.c | 2018-06-22
> ```

MySQL 8 added window functions *(FINALLY)*, and this makes a problem like this **MUCH** easier to solve, and likely much more efficient, too. You can sort the rows you need with a `ROW_NUMBER()` window function.

> ```
> /* MySQL 8+ */
> SELECT s1.ID, s1.team_id, s1.submission_file, s1.the_date
> FROM (
>   SELECT ID, team_id, submission_file, the_date
>     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team_id, submission_file ORDER BY the_date DESC) AS rn
>   FROM t1
> ) s1
> WHERE rn = 1
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | team_id | submission_file | the_date  
> -: | ------: | :-------------- | :---------
>  8 |    1756 | final_project.c | 2018-06-22
>  3 |    1756 | untitled.c      | 2018-06-21
>  6 |    1814 | my_project.c    | 2018-06-20
>  2 |    1923 | asdf.c          | 2018-06-22
>  4 |    1923 | my_project.c    | 2018-06-21
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bc2741d8653c63ff2560999bb869e78d)*

***NOTE:** After re-reading the OP, the intent may be different than what I originally read. In my queries, my filtering will return the most recent of all unique `submission_file` names that a team submitted. So if a team submitted 3 files, you will get all 3 of the most recent versions of those files. If you remove `submission_file` from the 5 subquery and the 8 `PARTITION BY`, it will return only the most recent single file a team submitted regardless of name.*

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e9bcddd0bb4c233c5a606303194b6c98 << Added examples of multiple `submission_file`s for same `team_id` at same time.